# Javascript code not working in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, codepen

I was trying to do my front-end with this [Codepen Template](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQxdXZ#anon-signup) but when i'm trying to click on the signup button, it's not changing to signup form for which the code is in the index.js file, i've included hte index.js file in the login.html.erb but when i'm running the rails server the transition isn't working. [My Rails Project](https://github.com/aashish-ak/QAengine), [Codepen Template](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQxdXZ#anon-signup) 
Here is the javascript code in index.js

```
document.querySelector('.img__btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.querySelector('.cont').classList.toggle('s--signup');  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your current JS code in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` within a `DOMContentLoadListener` *event listener*:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelector('.img__btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.cont').classList.toggle('s--signup');
  });
});
```

Comment: As you have two times the same piece of code, it can be done in the `application.js` or in the `index.js` file. You then might consider removing the repeated one.

Comment: Do RoR add the application.js code automatically or i have to add it manually with javascript_include_tag??

Comment: Also thanks @Sebastion, you again saved the day, it worked but can you please tell what is it exactly??

Comment: The js code in the `application.js` file is executed "automatically" by Rails, it's added in your application erb file and this also adds all what you set by using `//=`, the code in it appears at the bottom of the compiled file. And about the `DOMContentLoaded` you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) that's fired when the HTML has been totally loaded, so, this guarantees you all the needed file for your piece of code will be available @AashishKumar.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the path of index.js Add this line in app.html for including index js file .

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "index" %>
```

Comment: I've already added index.js in the asstes/javascripts folder which is the default folder for Ruby on Rails but it's still not working.

Comment: @AashishKumar  did u check the view source of page ?

Comment: no i haven't but the above answer by Sebastian worked, i have to include the js code in DOMContentLoaded, it worked, but i don't know about DOMContentLoaded, can you please tell me what it is??